# The database sqlmap is trying to read is too big. I time out every time

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

So I found the database and then the table and the columns and I'm trying to dump the column data but it is too big. It keep taking ~2 mins then timing out.

Comment: What method  of injection are you using?

Comment: Voted for migration to SO.

Comment: For optimization it's better to post your query at [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @peterh This won't do well on Stack Overflow. FIrst, it's not a programming question. Second, there's simply not enough information. Michael, I suggest you [edit] your question. For starters, tell us which sqlmap options you have tried. Please edit this information into your question.

Comment: This is quite common with "slow" methods such as time-based blind injection. In a security testing context, it's usually enough to show a few sensitive items (e.g. DB name, current user) to prove that the injection point exists without needing to dump the full DB.

Comment: What's the context? If this is a pen test, it would usually suffice to say "an attacker with more time could dump your database"

Comment: Maybe you need to optimize your exploit, limite the amount of records of your result and to know the kind of attack, for example, it could be a blind sql injection, but give more information.